# Gradle BuildException in NetBeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle

I want to run my gradle Java EE project using NetBeans on Ubuntu 12.04. 
Error - Project output:

```
Build failure: gradle run
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'
```

My gradle -version output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-08-06 11:19:56 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     9a7199efaf72c620b33f9767874f0ebced135d83

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.6.0_27 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b12)
OS:           Linux 3.2.0-52-generic-pae i386
```

and my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
mainClass = "main.Main"

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'main.Main'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '3.6.7.Final'
    compile "javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1"
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.13'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.13'
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.13'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

This error occurs when I'm trying to use Hibernate (create EntityManager):
NetBeans log:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named WebSISMSPUpgsql
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at jpa.EntityManagerFactory.reinit(EntityManagerFactory.java:69)
at jpa.EntityManagerFactory.<init>(EntityManagerFactory.java:61)
at jpa.EntityManagerFactory.<init>(EntityManagerFactory.java:56)
at jpa.EntityManagerFactory.getInstance(EntityManagerFactory.java:43)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:18)
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

What should I do about it?

Comment: Does the build work with command line Gradle? Isn't there a more detailed error message somewhere (e.g. in the Netbeans log)?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I added NetBeans output to the question.

Comment: and gradle build works ok from command line, gradle run crashes with the same log as netbeans

Comment: I don't understand. Does a `gradle run` on the command line succeed, or does it fail?

Comment: Does adding `sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` and executing `gradle clean run` solve the problem?

Comment: I added this into build.gradle but gradle clean run still fails - i think i have some problems with hibernate...